# Replace image url in ASP.NET image button using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working in asp.net and mysql. Will shows the details of rooms in page with images that getting for mysql database,. In the Main Image will change when i click the small size image buttons.

I want to replace the Image1 ImageUrl "~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=1" to "~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=2" or "~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=3" like this,. when clicking the regading imagebutton.

Please help me to get this in Jquery.

[image]

My Code,..

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=1" Height="178" Width="178"></asp:Image>   <br /><br />
                      &nbsp;
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=2" Height="30" Width="37" /> &nbsp;
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=3" Height="30" Width="37" />&nbsp;
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=4" Height="30" Width="37" />&nbsp;
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/GetRoomImage.aspx?id=5" Height="30" Width="37" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can bind an event for every small image click on page load and assigning the src from the small image to larger image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('input[type=image]').click(function(){

          var newImg = $(this).attr("src");
           $("#Image1").attr("src",newImg)
       });
});
```

Comment: I am not using html image, how to change the imageurl in asp. pls note my req. thanks

Comment: ASP.NET server controls will be rendered as html controls in browser, so `<asp:ImageButton>` will be rendered as `input[type=image]`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[value ^= 'ImageButton']").click(function(){
      var newImg = $(this).attr("src");
       $("#Image1").attr("src",newImg)
   });
});
```

Comment: can i change the src to ImageUrl. bzs i am using asp image